# How would I go about modifying an AOB from Cheat Engine to C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, byte, reverse-engineering, cheat-engine

I've been attempting to modify an array of bytes that I found inside of Cheat Engine inside of C++, but I've reached an Access Violation crash when I attempt to read or write from it.

```
    // Writes pillarbox removal into memory ("33 83 4C 02" to "33 83 4C 00").
    *(BYTE*)(*((intptr_t*)((intptr_t)baseModule + 0x1E14850)) + 0x3) = 00;
```

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong, as using something similar for the float values that I modified worked fine once I unprotected the main module handle.

Comment: What tools are you using to compile/run this C++? For those of us unfamiliar with Cheat Engine.

Comment: I assume `baseModule + 0x1e14850` holds the address of the `0x33834c02` data and shouldn't hold the data itself?

Comment: @JohnFileau I'm using Visual Studio 2019, alongside ASI Loader.

Comment: I assume the AOB CE scan returned you `BaseModule+0x1E14850` adress. If you want to write 00 to process memory, why not use `WriteProcessMemory` ?

Comment: @user The address itself where the AOB is, according to Cheat Engine's address properties was the game process + 1E14850, which is where I got that from.

Comment: I just don't understand, this c++ code would change the memory if it's a dll injected into the game, is that how you are doing ? Running this code from a compiled program will not change a game's memory, for that you'd need to use `WriteProcessMemory`. You need to add a more information on what you're doing

Comment: @user Yes. It's a DLL file that gets loaded by ASI Loader.

I'm attempting to change the 02 byte in that byte array to disable the pillarboxing used in a UE4 game when running on a display wider than 16:9.

Comment: have you checked in the CE disasembler that address `baseModule + 0x1e14850` indeed holds `33 83 4C 02` to begin with ?

Comment: @user, I can confirm that it indeed does, when I looked at it in the CE disassembler.

Comment: have you made sure your dll code gets executed, say by throwing a msgbox for instance ?

Comment: @user, yes I can confirm that my DLL code gets executed. It's just that when I attempt to write said byte value to memory, it causes the game to crash.

Using this to change the field of view works fine though: *(float*)((intptr_t)baseModule + 0x2CD03B0) = (float)FOV;

Comment: check if the memory you are attempting to change has Write access, for this in CE disasembler : view memory regions

Comment: The page protection is read execute, according to Cheat Engine's disassembler, @user.

I was able to unprotect the module handle by using "ScopedUnprotect::FullModule UnProtect(baseModule);;" with the float values, but that doesn't seem to work with the bytes.

Comment: hmm at this point it's more reverse engineering than C++, but either way if you changed the protection shouldn't it also show in the CE memorymap ?

Comment: Yes, with the protection changed, it shows that it's read/write/execute in Cheat Engine's disassembler.

Comment: game has anticheat protection ? try put a breakpoint before the address you intend to change, then inject the dll, then check if the dll changed any byte

Comment: @user The game doesn't have anti-cheat protection, as I was able to edit the bytes in Cheat Engine's address list just fine.

Comment: can you edit your question with the dll full code (or at least the code we need to see, but make it minimal reproductible example) ? also what injector are you using ?

Comment: @user, I am using ASI Loader to inject the DLL.

As for the full DLL code, here it is: https://github.com/KingKrouch/21xMachi9/blob/master/Source/dllmain.cpp

As for the link to ASI Loader:

https://github.com/ThirteenAG/Ultimate-ASI-Loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
void WriteToMemory(uintptr_t addressToWrite, char* valueToWrite, int byteNum)
{
    //used to change our file access type, stores the old
    //access type and restores it after memory is written
    unsigned long OldProtection;
    //give that address read and write permissions and store the old permissions at oldProtection
    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)(addressToWrite), byteNum, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &OldProtection);

    //write the memory into the program and overwrite previous value
    memcpy((LPVOID)addressToWrite, valueToWrite, byteNum);

    //reset the permissions of the address back to oldProtection after writting memory
    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)(addressToWrite), byteNum, OldProtection, NULL);
}
```

and call it as such :

```
MODULEINFO mInfo = GetModuleInfo("name.exe");

//Assign our base and module size
DWORD baseModule = (DWORD)mInfo.lpBaseOfDll;
uintptr_t addressToWrite = (uintptr_t)baseModule + 0x1E14850;
char writeThis[] = "\x33\x83\x4c\x00";
WriteToMemory(addressToWrite, writeThis, 4);
```

Please let me know if it worked

Comment: It appears as if an error that says "a value of type "HMODULE" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "uintptr_t"" around the baseModule variable of that function call.

Comment: By replacing what threw that error to " uintptr_t addressToWrite = ((intptr_t)baseModule + 0x1E14850);", it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: great, glad we could do it in the end

Comment: @KingKrouch just for the sake of it https://guidedhacking.com/threads/c-signature-scan-pattern-scanning-tutorial.3981/ shows quite similar code which includes a (really bad optimized - yet sort of working) pattern scan byte inside the dll, which would avoid you having to use CE to do AOB scan every time you start the game.